# ELB metrics not found in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a load balancer in ap-northeast-1 (Tokyo) region.

According to this [article](http://blog.celingest.com/en/2013/11/07/understanding-new-elb-metrics-in-cloudwatch/), I think I should be able to find *Backend Connection Errors*, *Surge Queue Length*, and *Spillovers* metrics in CloudWatch. But I can't find them.

Are these metrics only available in specific regions?

I've googled for hours but failed to find an answer.

Currently I can see 15 metric for my ELB, which are

1. *Average Latency*
2. *Sum Requests*
3. *Sum HTTP 5XXs*
4. *Sum HTTP 4XXs*
5. *Sum ELB 5XXs*
6. *Sum ELB 4XXs*
7. *Target connection errors*
8. *Sum rejected connections*
9. *Target TLS Negotiation Errors*
10. *Sum HTTP 3XXs*
11. *Sum HTTP 3XXs*
12. *Sum HTTP 2XXs*
13. *Active Connection Count*
14. *New Connection Count*
15. *Processed Bytes*

Answer (score 7):

The AWS documentation lists:

- [CloudWatch Metrics for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html)
- [CloudWatch Metrics for Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html)

The Classic list includes:

- **BackendConnectionErrors:** The number of connections that were not successfully established between the load balancer and the registered instances.
- **SurgeQueueLength:** The total number of requests that are pending routing.
- **SpilloverCount:** The total number of requests that were rejected because the surge queue is full.

If these metrics are not appearing, it may be because the values are **zero**. Typically, zero values are not sent to Amazon CloudWatch.

Comment: If using an Application Load Balancer and you're looking to find a useful metric for dynamic autoscaling what would you recommend given Surge QueueLength and SpilloverCount are not available?

Comment: `Latency` is a good ELB metric for identifying how 'busy' the instances are, assuming that more busy instances respond slower. Alternatively, base the scaling on metrics associated with the Auto Scaling group, or some measure of how much work the application needs to perform (eg size of an input queue, if applicable).

Comment: This article really helped me with this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=140404 It confirms what @JohnRotenstein mentioned about metrics not appearing.